# Arraylist override values issue?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-spinner

I have an object of Order Items.it contains three values

1.item Name

2.Item Price

3.No of Items

I have a spinner, i have add this object on item selected.

When I add this object and select again , an other item it will also add into list, not override.

My code is below

```
    private OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println("parent Tag:"+arg0.getTag());
        TextView itemName = (TextView)findViewById(Integer.parseInt(arg0.getTag().toString()));
        System.out.println("Item Name:" +itemName.getText().toString());
        System.out.println("Item Price:" +itemName.getTag().toString());
        System.out.println("Item QTY:" +arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
        orderItems = new OrderItems();          
        if(!"".equals(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString())){
            orderItems.itemName = itemName.getText().toString();
            orderItems.itemPrice = itemName.getTag().toString();
            orderItems.noOfItems = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
            //if(itemsArray)
            itemsArray.additem(orderItems);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

public void additem(OrderItems object){
    itemArrayList.add(object);
}
```

can any body help me in this?
What i am missing here?

Comment: `itemsArray.additem(orderItems);` , you want to add in `orderItems` right ?

Comment: @SURESH ATTA I want to check if the selected item already exists then override it

Comment: @Caleryn I have edit my question you can check out.
public void additem(OrderItems object){
  itemArrayList.add(object);
 }
this is my code

Comment: @Nadeem Ok so you are adding to the end of the ArrayList, this function will only ever add an object it explicitly allows for multiple copies of the same thing. If you wnat a single copy of each item you need a Set not a List  you will also need to override both equals and hashcode on your OrderItems object

Comment: @Caleryn yes this is the problem

Comment: @Caleryn can you help me in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
HashMap<Integer,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
private OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {   
       System.out.println("parent Tag:"+arg0.getTag());
       TextView itemName = (TextView)findViewById(Integer.parseInt(arg0.getTag().toString()));
       System.out.println("Item Name:" +itemName.getText().toString());
       System.out.println("Item Price:" +itemName.getTag().toString());
       System.out.println("Item QTY:" +arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
       orderItems = new OrderItems();
       if(!"".equals(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString())){
          orderItems.itemName = itemName.getText().toString();
          orderItems.itemPrice = itemName.getTag().toString();
          orderItems.noOfItems = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
          hashMap.put(arg2,orderItems);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

   }
};
```

Comment: Glad to help you can you please upvote if it is useful to you ?

Comment: i tried to upvote but i have less reputations.
But i have done as accepted answer. sorry for upvote

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. @HareshChhelana please do you think you could give me your opinion on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse/25599152?noredirect=1#comment40016780_25599152

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if the selected item is already in the `itemArrayList` you need to override the `equals and hashcode` function in your `OrderItems` class

```
class OrderItems{

//your methods

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (this == obj)
            return true;

        if (obj == null || (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        OrderItems order = (OrderItems) obj;
        return this.itemName.equals(order.getItemName())
                && this.itemPrice.equals(order.getItemPrice())
                && this.noOfItems.equals(order.getNoOfItems());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemName != null ? itemName.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

then in your `onItemSelected` function you can just use the `contains` method of the arraylist

```
         orderItems = new OrderItems(); 

        if(!itemArrayList.contains(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2))){
            orderItems.itemName = itemName.getText().toString();
            orderItems.itemPrice = itemName.getTag().toString();
            orderItems.noOfItems = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
            //if(itemsArray)
            itemsArray.additem(orderItems);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you declare itemArrayList

```
 Set<OrderItems> itemArrayList = new HashSet<>();
```

The following two methods or equivalents dependant upon your needs should exist on the OrderItems object.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 43 * 3 + (this.itemName != null ? this.itemName.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 43 * hash + (this.itemPrice != null ? this.itemPrice.hashCode() : 0);
    return 43 * hash + this.noOfItems;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj){
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final OrderItems other = (OrderItems) obj;
    if ((this.itemName == null) ? (other.itemName != null) : !this.itemName.equals(other.itemName)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.itemPrice != other.itemPrice && (this.itemPrice == null || !this.itemPrice.equals(other.itemPrice))) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.noOfItems == other.noOfItems;
}
```

I have included all fields in both cases adjust both methods so that your equality condition (is when an OrderItems object is the same) is correct for BOTH functions.

the remainder of you r code should be close to unchanged.

I used an AutoGeneration algorithm to give me the equals and hashCode functions you may wish to do the same. rather than copy mine